# Facebook QR Code Like through iPhone Application

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, qr-code

I am trying to create a QR Code that if scanned on a phone that has the Facebook application installed, the Facebook application will go directly to the like page saved in the QR code. I have tried what [this website](http://www.insidefacebook.com/2011/10/21/facebook-url-scheme-pages/) has said, and it did not work. It opened the Facebook application but did not go to the page.

I'm trying to redirect to [this Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/ViralGliders).

I would greatly appreciate anyone's help if they can give me a pointer. I am not a programmer or a technical person, so my knowledge is limited. But, I am willing learn. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a link to the QR code that you've tried?

Comment: Yes, I have tried the following link:

Comment: Oops let me add it fb://page/279522875481579/

Comment: Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook page automatic "like" URL (for QR Code)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763046/facebook-page-automatic-like-url-for-qr-code)

Answer (score 1):

Something you could do is use a landing page service that lets you add 'like' buttons. 
One that's free: [www.likify.net](http://www.likify.net).

I'm not sure you can open Facebook urls in the facebook app directly. As far as I know, only the app store and itunes can do this on iPhone.

Comment: Any application should be able to send to Facebook by using fb:// instead of http:// in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

When I try to access facebook.com/ViralGliders even through my browser, it just takes me to the facebook homepage. Maybe this is an incorrect URL, or you have some permission issues..?