# QR code format for geolocation

Tags: iphone, ios, geolocation, qr-code

I am developing a QR code generator where I need to make QR code codes for various datas. One of them is geolocation and social network (likes in Facebook and follow in Twitter).

I am okay with other formats however the above two items are still not clear to me. What is the specific format to get them done?

Comment: While reading some article some writer have written that some formats can not be scanned in android made in iPhone. Is it true? I am developing the app for Iphone though I want to support other smart phones as well.

Answer (score 4):

A geo URI may be used to encode a point on the earth, including altitude. For example, to encode the Google's New York office, which is at 40.71872 deg N latitude, 73.98905 deg W longitude, at a point 100 meters above the office, one would encode "geo:40.71872,-73.98905,100".

A reader might open a local mapping application like Google Maps to this location and zoom accordingly, or could open a link to this location on a mapping web site like Google Maps in the device's web browser.

Please follow the specific format.

Comment: This is the only valid answer, only the format `geo:12.34,56.78,900` (`lat,lng,distance`) is recognized by bar code scanner apps as geolocation. Google Maps app doesn't support it however. If I open map through Barcoo and chose Google Maps, it will open the app but without query. Some other data types / keywords are listed here: http://www.mobilefish.com/tutorials/qrcode/qrcode.html

Answer (score -1):

For a geolocation, expressed as latitude, longitude coordinate i would code this way:
uncoded coordinate in degrees WGS84: lat=48.123456 lon=-120.123456
for coded string multiply each coord with 1E6:

string reprsentation: "(48123456,-120123456)"

Comment: would you please elaborate the format more like what should be the string?

Comment: the string is rhe string between the quotes, if you need an identifier like "latLong=" you may add that befire he coordibaze, but this probabky you know bettet fir qrcodes

Comment: Barcoo won't recognize such a representation: [Test QR code](https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=geo%3A(48123456%2C-120123456)&size=220x220&margin=0)

Answer (score -1):

QR codes store alphanumeric data. If you can write code able to read them (or integrate a third part library) you can do whatever you want with them, e.g. you can store coordinates in Well Known Format [WKF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text)

To like something from a QR code please refer to this answer: [Facebook page automatic "like" URL (for QR Code)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763046/facebook-page-automatic-like-url-for-qr-code)

Normally, Existing qr code readers expect an url.

With regard to the supported devices: all depends on the libraries used to read the qrcode, it does not depends on the device itself.

Comment: ...like I am doing for vcard and mecard...there are formats...for sms there are formats....like that....I want formats for geolocation.....please help me if you can...

Answer (score -1):

I implement a lat and lng coordinates map qr code on my qr code generator http://www.qrcode-generator24.com. Put the marker on the google map and the coordinates will be stored in a form like lng:39.7676745 lat:20.7634834. Bear in mind that not all qr code reader are able to recognize that content as map coordinates.

Comment: Barcoo doesn't recognize `lng:39.7 lat:20.7`, nor if preceded by `geo:`. Same goes for manually entered query in Google Maps app.

Answer (score -1):

I did it by geo:lat(numerical value),lang(numerical value) to bring up the geo location qr code and it works good in any scanner.

Comment: Barcoo won't recognize lat(...),long(...).