# Facebook Page Like and Show Page

Tags: android, facebook, qr-code, facebook-like

Background:
I am trying to increase engagement on my facebook page, buy sending a link or a scannable QR code to clients inviting them to like and view our Facebook page. This would take them to our main Facebook page, like the page if not already, and otherwise allow the user to browse our Facebook page and its content. To be clear: The message or the QR hand out would indicate a message along the lines of "Scan this code/click this link to like and view our page!".

I have tried the solutions listed on the following page, as it is the most similar, just not quite what I am trying to do:

[Facebook page automatic "like" URL (for QR Code)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763046/facebook-page-automatic-like-url-for-qr-code)

The below two options, when scanned via QR code, successfully opens the facebook app, but only to the user's landing page. Not our page.

`fb://page/(pageID)/addfan`
`fb://profile/(pageID)/addfan`

The below options opens a Facebook Error Page.

[www.facebook.com/(PageID)/like](http://www.facebook.com/(PageID)/like)

m.facebook.com/(PageID)/like

Using Facebook's Dev Plugin method works to embed on a website, or as a link with a small like button, but does not then allow for direct page viewing.

The following methods appear to only show a small like button.

`fb://page/(PageID)?referrer=app_link`

https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http://facebook.com/Pagename

The below method only brings up the page itself on a browser, but with no content other than the header (cover photo, profile picture topics etc).

https://www.facebook.com/PageName?sk=likes